# Python Regular Expression with special characters

Tags: python, regex, string

Having trouble writing a robust regular expression to grab information out of a string.

```
$ string1 = 'A_XYZ_THESE_WORDS'
$ string2 = 'A_ABC_THOSE_WORDS'
```

I would like a robust solution that pulls out from string1 or string2 respectfully 'THESE_WORDS' or 'THOSE_WORDS'.

Basically, I need something that removes everything before the first two underscores (_), but the text before them will vary.

```
$ get_text = re.search('(?<=A_)\w+(_)',string1)
$ print get_text.group()
$ 'XYZ_THESE_'
```

Comment: The underscore is not a special character in regex. Also, your explanation is ambiguous, *"everything before the first two underscores"* is not precise enough.

Comment: Do you need a regex? Why not `string1.split("_", 2)[2]`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe You might consider posting that as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your problem statement:

> I need something that removes everything before the first two underscores

you don't necessarily need a regular expression:

```
>>> string1 = 'A_XYZ_THESE_WORDS'
>>> string1.split("_", 2)[2]
'THESE_WORDS'
```

The second argument to [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) is the maximum number of times to split. This will split on the first two `'_'`s, then take the third item (the rest of the string) from the resulting list.

This will throw an `IndexError` if there are fewer than two underscores in the string - this lets you know that the string is not in a format you expect, but if this behaviour is not desirable, consider:

```
>>> string1 = 'A_XYZ_THESE_WORDS'
>>> string1.split("_", 2)[-1]
'THESE_WORDS'
```

Which takes the *last* item in the list from `str.split`, rather than assuming that there will be three. Comparison:

```
>>> "JUST_ONE".split("_", 2)[2]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    "JUST_ONE".split("_", 2)[2]
IndexError: list index out of range

>>> "JUST_ONE".split("_", 2)[-1]
'ONE'
```

Comment: It took me a minute to spot that the difference is the `2` vs. `-1` index.

Answer (score 1):

The below regex will print the texts which was just after to the second underscore(_),

```
>>> import re
>>> string1 = 'A_XYZ_THESE_WORDS'
>>> string2 = 'A_ABC_THOSE_WORDS'
>>> m = re.search(r'^[^_]*_[^_]*_(.*)$', string1)
>>> m.group(1)
'THESE_WORDS'
>>> m = re.search(r'^[^_]*_[^_]*_(.*)$', string2)
>>> m.group(1)
'THOSE_WORDS'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In [21]: regex = re.compile(r'^([a-zA-Z]+_){2}(.*)$')

In [22]: m = regex.search(string1)

In [23]: m.groups()
Out[23]: ('XYZ_', 'THESE_WORDS')

In [24]: m = regex.search(string2)

In [25]: m.groups()
Out[25]: ('ABC_', 'THOSE_WORDS')
```

Comment: If the OP isn't interested in the first part, that group can be eliminated from the results simply by removing the first set of parentheses. Otherwise, great answer.

Comment: @jpmc26, I need the those parentheses for the `{2}` multiplier, although for such a small multiplier the regular expression could be "unrolled".